# При Выполнении скрипта ошибка Cannot index into a null array

Tags: sql, powershell, azure

Всем привет, ошибка после выполнения скрипта:

```
#$srv = New-Object (“Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server”)$conn


Function Add-UserToRole ([String] $Database , [string]$User, [string]$Role)
{
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"
$cn = "Server=tcp:testsql01nau.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=test;Password=QWERTY123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $cn
$srv = New-Object (“Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server”)$conn
#Check Database Name entered correctly
$db = $svr.Databases[$Database]
    if($db -eq $null)
        {
        Write-Output " $Database is not a valid database on $Server"
        Write-Output " Databases on $Server are :"
        $svr.Databases|select name
        break
        }
#Check Role exists on Database
        $Rol = $db.Roles[$Role]
    if($Rol -eq $null)
        {
        Write-Output " $Role is not a valid Role on $Database on $Server  "
        Write-Output " Roles on $Database are:"
        $db.roles|select name
        break
        }
    if(!($svr.Logins.Contains($User)))
        {
        Write-Output "$User not a login on $server create it first"
        break
        }
    if (!($db.Users.Contains($User)))
        {
        # Add user to database

        $usr = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User') ($db, $User)
        $usr.Login = $User
        $usr.Create()

        #Add User to the Role
        $Rol = $db.Roles[$Role]
        $Rol.AddMember($User)
        Write-Output "$User was not a login on $Database on $server"
        Write-Output "$User added to $Database on $Server and $Role Role"
        }
        else
        {
         #Add User to the Role
        $Rol = $db.Roles[$Role]
        $Rol.AddMember($User)
        Write-Output "$User added to $Role Role in $Database on $Server "
        }
}

Add-UserToRole -Database "testnew1" -User "bro" -Role "data_reader"
```

Может кто то помочь? Спасибо

Comment: И что вы хотите от нас? Вам перевести ошибку на русский?

Comment: Банальные опечатки: `srv != svr`.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а как изменить скрипт, что бы добавлять не одного пользоавтеля, а анпример 3